# How to center the itemize section in beamer?

Tags: beamer

I divided a frame into two columns and I want to put the items at the horizontal center of the left columns. It seems `\begin{center}` doesn't work in this case.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{frame}{1D Stefan Problem}
\color{red}\rule{.5\linewidth}{4pt}\color{blue}\rule{.5\linewidth}{4pt}
\begin{columns}[c]
    \column{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item $u_{t}=k_{L}u_{xx}$
    \end{itemize}
    \end{center}
    \column{.5\textwidth}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

And the output:
[image]

Comment: Do you still want the bullets to line up, so only the whole list is centered as one block, or do you want each individual item centered individually so the bullets for longer items are further left than the others?

Comment: @frabjous Hi! Sorry for the confusion. I actually want the whole list to be centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a better way than putting the lists inside a minipage or parbox of the appropriate size. You would need to tweak the width to fit the list, and maybe even add a little extra to balance with the left indentation for itemize bullets. (It tried a varwidth environment so you wouldn't have to guess the width manually but it doesn't seem to work well with lists.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{1D Stefan Problem}


\begin{columns}[c]

    \column{.5\textwidth}

    \color{red}\rule{\linewidth}{4pt}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{3.1cm}
            \noindent\begin{itemize}
                \item $u_{t}=k_{L}u_{xx}$
                \item $x^2  + y^2 = z^2$
            \end{itemize}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    \column{.5\textwidth}

    \color{blue}\rule{\linewidth}{4pt}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{2.6cm}
            \noindent\begin{itemize}
                \item $E = mc^2$
                \item $1+1=2$
            \end{itemize}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: beamer centered list]

(Note I moved your red and blue bars as they were a little misleading where they were. The columns environment changes the margins and adds space between the columns.)

But there may be better ways.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The minipage method works well. And I move `\rule` out of the column section to get a continuous rectangle.